# How to persistently get Battery level and Charging status in Android (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, battery, foreground-service

I want to get the battery level and charging status(plugged or unplugged) persistently for my app, i.e every 3-4 seconds, or better, only when it changes.

Currently I am doing this:

```
        val bm = getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager 
         val manager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(this,NotificationManager::class.java) as NotificationManager 
         val intent = this.registerReceiver(null, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) 
         val plugged = intent?.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1) ?: -1 
         val chargingText = when (plugged) { 
             BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC -> { 
                 "Charging via AC supply" 
             } 
             BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB -> { 
                 "Charging via USB" 
             } 
             BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS -> { 
                 "Charging by Wireless technology" 
             } 
             else -> { 
                 "Discharging" 
             } 
         } 
         val batLevel:Int = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)
```

I put the above code in a fixed rate timer for a 3.5 sec interval.

I think this is pretty expensive on battery as it runs on a Foreground service continuously. But I need to get the exact level persistently.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so - [this is the official guidance](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#CurrentLevel) and they have this to say

> **You can't easily continually monitor the battery state, but you don't need to.**
>
> Generally speaking, **the impact of constantly monitoring the battery level has a greater impact on the battery than your app's normal behavior, so it's good practice to only monitor significant changes in battery level**—specifically when the device enters or exits a low battery state.

Sounds pretty much like "there's no efficient way to do this, so don't". Do you really need to check the battery every 4 seconds though? Even doing intensive stuff it doesn't drain *that* quickly (depends on the battery size and health yeah, but still)

If you really do need that kind of accuracy but you want it to be more efficient, maybe you could poll it less often, but speed that up as it gets closer to a change. If you click that link I posted, they have an example where they calculate the current percentage from the `LEVEL` and `SCALE` values, which are some raw capacity numbers - I don't know if it's mAh or what, but they're getting fractional percentages either way (instead of the rounded integer you're using). So maybe you could use that to back off the updates until that fraction gets closer to zero? Maybe track the drain rate and factor that in too

Comment: My app shows user how much battery is remaining, in big fonts, and also provides other battery related information. So you can see, I need to get it accurately.

Comment: Also I saw the link but could not figure out how to go about your said tactic. Can you post some code?

Comment: @coderGtm well you only need it to be running while the user is looking at it, right? So that's probably not so bad, especially if "looking at the battery" is the app's whole deal. As far as the code goes, instead of a `Timer` or whatever, you'd have a `Runnable` task you post to a `Handler` with a delay, a coroutine that calls `delay` or a thread that calls `sleep`, that kind of thing. And instead of always delaying by 4000 milliseconds, you'd make it longer the further you are from the whole number. `delay = if (percent % 1f > 0.5) 30000 else 4000`, that sort of deal

Comment: The app runs a foreground service(24 hrs) also, as I mentioned in the question. I use it to notify battery level in the notification bar. As of the code, I still can't grasp if there is a better approach to eventually polling the info. Can't I get it any other way?